# Как получить доступ к потоку входящих/выходящих через WiFi адаптер (или соединение с интернетом) данных?

Tags: linux, потоки-данных

Проблема такая: У меня usb-адаптер для wi-fi. На нем лампочка, которая показывает активность. Она почему-то показывает активность также и при простое системы (без дела). На других машинах и с другими ОС (На моей машине Linux Mint стоит) подобного не наблюдалось (При использовании этого же адаптера). Так вот, вопрос -  Как посмотреть что это за гора данных, которая летит з/в интернет?

Если не найдется решение, то буду доволен и хорошим советом на тему "В каких книгах можно поискать ответа на мой вопрос?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лампочка мигает при приеме и передаче данных. Это может быть связанно с обменом не только с интернет, но и с локальной сетью, например другим компьютером.

Также в usb адаптере эта лампочка обычно управляется драйвером. В других ОС там установлен другой порог срабатывания. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=121903 вот тут  и тут https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless#Disabling_LED_blink, например, нашли как настроить режим моргания. Но решение может не подойти к вашему драйверу

Посмотреть что там пролетает можно командой tcpdump или программой wireshark

```
tcpdump -vvv -i wlp3s0
```

Где wlp3s0 имя адаптера, иногда wlan0.