# Как понять, с кем и почему мой компьютер обменивается данными?

Tags: linux, потоки-данных, wifi

Задал [вопрос про лампочку на usb-wifi адаптере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-wifi-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd/1188705#1188705).

Чтобы посмотреть, что пролетает через адаптер дал команду `tcpdump -vvv -i my_wifi`. На выходе обнаружил, что мой юзер (в системе линукс) постоянно обменивается с многими IP адресами (пока я тут). Так же обменивается данными в простое системы.
Как понять с кем и почему в простое обменивается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через программу netstat можно посмотреть список программ работающих с сетью.

```
netstat -p
```

Открытые порты

```
netstat -tpl
netstat -upl
```

Кому принадлежат IP адреса можно посмотреть на сервисе whois https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/query?bflag=false&dflag=false&rflag=true&searchtext=8.8.8.8&source=GRS